# This program selecting the whole row, how to limit selection to A to M

Tags: vba, excel

```
Sub Test()

Dim Cell As Range

With Sheets(1)
    ' loop column H untill last cell with value (not entire column)
    For Each Cell In .Range("A1:A" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
        If Cell.Value = "0" Then
             ' Copy>>Paste in 1-line (no need to use Select)
            .Rows(Cell.Row).Copy Destination:=Sheets(4).Rows(Cell.Row)
        End If
    Next Cell
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
Sub Test()

Dim Cell As Range

With Sheets(1)
    ' loop column H untill last cell with value (not entire column)
    For Each Cell In .Range("A1:A" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
        If Cell.Value = "0" Then
             ' Copy>>Paste in 1-line (no need to use Select)
             Dim targetRow As Long
             targetRow = Cell.Row
            .Range("A" & targetRow & ":H" & targetRow).Copy Destination:=Sheets(4).Rows(Cell.Row)
        End If
    Next Cell
End With

End Sub
```

### But

as that produces a weird repeated paste, did you actually want? Note I replaced the variable  cell with currentCell to avoid confusion

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

    Dim currentCell As Range

    With Sheets(1)

        For Each currentCell In .Range("A1:A" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
        
            If currentCell.Value = "0" Then
        
                Dim targetRow As Long
                targetRow = currentCell.Row
                .Range("A" & targetRow & ":H" & targetRow).Copy Destination:=Sheets(4).Cells(currentCell.Row, 1)

            End If
        
        Next currentCell
    
    End With

End Sub
```

### And:

As noted by @DisplayName you mention column H in your comment. If you intend to loop this then change:

```
For Each currentCell In .Range("A1:A" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
```

For

```
 For Each currentCell In .Range("H1:H" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here are some other options for replacing this:

```
.Rows(Cell.Row).Copy
```

With either of the following:

1. `Cell.Resize(1,13).Copy`
2. `Intersect(Cell.EntireRow, .Range("A:M")).Copy`

Or you can loop through the *row* rather than a specific cell:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim currentRow As Range
    With Sheets(1)
        ' loop column H untill last cell with value (not entire column)
        For Each currentRow In .Range("A1:M" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).Rows
            If currentRow.Cells(1, 1).Value = "0" Then
                 ' Copy>>Paste in 1-line (no need to use Select)
                currentRow.Copy Destination:=Sheets(4).Rows(currentRow.Row)
            End If
        Next Cell
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

use

```
.Range("A:M").Rows(Cell.row).Copy Destination:=Sheets(4).Rows(Cell.row)
```

but you may be in the wrong column, since you're commenting:

```
' loop column H until last cell with value (not entire column)
```

while you coding:

```
For Each Cell In .Range("A1:A" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row)
```

i.e. your looping through column A!

so you may want to code:

```
Sub Test()

    Dim cell As Range

    With Sheets(1)
        ' loop column H until last cell with value (not entire column)
        For Each cell In .Range("H1:H" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row) ' loop through column H cells from row 1 down to last not empty row in column A
            If cell.Value = "0" Then .Range("A:M").Rows(cell.row).Copy Destination:=Sheets(4).Rows(cell.row)
        Next cell
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
Sub Test()
  Dim Cell As Range

  With Sheets(1)
    ' loop column H untill last cell with value (not entire column)
    For Each Cell In .Range("A1:A" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
      If Cell.Value = "0" Then
            ' Copy>>Paste in 1-line (no need to use Select)
        Sheets(4).Range("A:" & Cell.Row & ":M" & Cell.Row).Value = .Range("A:" & Cell.Row & ":M" & Cell.Row).Value
      End If
    Next Cell
  End With
End Sub
```